# jQuery errorContainer practice

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to be able to place the error message when using  jQuery validation to a asp.net label if the textbox is empty.

please advice how to modify my code to get that!!

here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#aspnetForm").validate({
            errorContainer: "#<%=TextBox1 %>",
            errorLabelContainer: "#<%=TextBox1 %> #<%=Label1 %>",
                wrapper: "li", debug: true,
                submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
            })
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    <p style="height: 313px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="required"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"  ></asp:Label>  
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
"#<%=TextBox1 %>"
```

means write the value of the default property of the textbox, which is the .Text property.

You should use

```
"#<%=TextBox1.ID %>"
```

and

```
"#<%=TextBox1.ID %> #<%=Label1.ID %>"
```

Comment: Close, you want `.ClientID` in this case though, in case it's inside a naming container.

Answer (score 0):

No to disqualify what you are doing now but I can't wrap my head around why you add a new plugin like JQ validation when you have a simple case of a required field validator which is a built in .net control